# SharedPreferences to load gold/silver/bronze on level selection screen

Tags: android, button, background, sharedpreferences

I have a game which has a gold/silver/bronze award threshold for score. The game saves the award achieved in a SharedPreferences file with the key being the level number. So on my level select screen, I have 20 levels. My code looks like this:

```
    private void initButtons() {
    Button b1 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b1));

    load = getSharedPreferences(Game.DATA, Game.GOLD);
    if(load.getInt(Integer.toString(1), 0) == 4){
    b1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.gold));
    b1.setText("1");
    b1.setTextSize(30);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b2)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b3)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b4)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b5)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b6)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b7)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b8)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b9)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b10)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b11)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b12)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b13)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b14)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b15)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b16)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b17)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b18)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b19)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b20)).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

So I would need 3 if, else if statements for each button. That seems like a lot. Is the above code efficient or should I use another method?

Thanks for the help
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static int[] button_id{R.id.b1,R.id.b2.....};
private void initButtons() {
    for(int i=0;i<button_id.length;i++){
        Button ONE_OF_YOUR_BUTTON=getButton(button_id[i]);
        ONE_OF_YOUR_BUTTON.doStuffToIt();
    }
}


    }

private static Button getButton(int id){
    return (Button)findViewById(id));
}
```

}

You can always loop it through. And These kind of question belong in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't realise ID's were numbers. I can use that to loop through Drawables too.

Sorry if the question belonged somewhere else, I'm new and thought that it fitted the guidelines.

Comment: Its ok Code Review is new. These kind of question still can come here I guess(not sure) but Code review is built for this.